# How to get typed listbox item

Tags: powershell, listbox

I created a powershell form with a few entry fields that are checked for input before doing any further actions. One of them is a listbox with a set of numbers representing printer numbers in our organization.

When the end-user selects the item with the printer via the dropdown menu, my script can perfectly read via .SelectedItem. However, they can also type the number in the field, and I am struggling to find how to get the value from the field when it is typed instead of selected.

Listbox :

```
$dropdown_Machine = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
    $dropdown_Machine.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,215)
    $dropdown_Machine.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,50)
    $dropdown_Machine.Font = $DROPDOWNFONT
    [void] $dropdown_Machine.Items.Add(" ")
    [void] $dropdown_Machine.Items.Add("729")
    [void] $dropdown_Machine.Items.Add("730")
    [void] $dropdown_Machine.Items.Add("744")
    ... some more items ...
    $Form_PrintLabel.Controls.Add($dropdown_Machine)
```

My check that is working when selected :

```
$searchmach = $dropdown_Machine.SelectedItem
```

When it is typed, it gives me an empty string. When it is selected it gives me the input I expected.

Can anyone push me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($dropdown_Machine.SelectedIndex -eq -1) { # nothing selected
    $dropdown_Machine.Text
} else {
    $dropdown_Machine.SelectedItem
}
```